# Natural scrolling / reverse scrolling with touchpad (only) is not working (reliably) on Kubuntu 18.10 (plasma 5.13.5)

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, plasma, plasma-5

Note: This worked all right in Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I am using a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.10, with the default plasma version that comes with it: 5.13.5.

The option in *System Settings* keeps getting reverted every few minutes. On visiting again, it shows a message meaning that the "Options visible are different from those in effect" and on refreshing, option gets unchecked. Screenshot:
[image: Auto reverting settings]

xinput method, `xinput --set-button-map 13 1 2 3 5 4 6 7`,found in some answers is causing unreliable effect, i.e. some of the apps start working reverse while some work inverted of inverted (i.e. original default).

Xorg method of setting `Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"` is having no effect.
[image: Xorg method]

Is there a reliable, permanent method of setting "natural scrolling" in Kubuntu 18.10?

**Update 1:**
I have seen that some of the options like X config work on boot, but at some point stop working randomly. I have not been able to pinpoint what causes it though (yet).

**Update 2:**
Confirming that my natural scrolling option keeps getting reverted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug specifically in the plasma version in question, 5.13.5, which ships by default with Kubuntu 18.10. I installed 5.14 and this seems to have resolved itself.